# How to display static direction with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to add on my site some maps concerning my itinerary.

I've created a customized style with the Google Maps Javascript API.

All the examples I've seen contain the input  in the HTML file, so users can insert origin and destination,

but I don't wanna that. My aim is to display only a "static" map with direction such as from Orlando to Key West with my custom style.

Can anyone help me with the code?

Thank you very much!

This is my custom style:

```
function initMap() {
  var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([
      {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "invert_lightness": true
            },
            {
                "saturation": 10
            },
            {
                "lightness": 30
            },
            {
                "gamma": 0.5
            },
            {
                "hue": "#435158"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": "0"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "6"
            },
            {
                "gamma": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
    ], {
      name: 'Leonardo'
  });
  var customMapTypeId = 'custom_style';

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {lat: 28, lng: -81.946},  // Florida.
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, customMapTypeId]
    }
  });




  map.mapTypes.set(customMapTypeId, customMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId(customMapTypeId);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a _"static"_ map as in the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Paths) where you can draw paths between locations?  Or just using the Javascript API, but instead of having form fields and event listeners like in [the example here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) you have your origin and destination hardcoded in your javascript?

Comment: Just using the Javascript API with origin and destination hardcoded, without form fields! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
        function initMap() {
            var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
                [
                    {
                        "featureType": "all",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {"invert_lightness": true}, 
                            {"saturation": 10}, 
                            {"lightness": 30}, 
                            {"gamma": 0.5}, 
                            {"hue": "#435158"}
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "featureType": "water",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {"saturation": "0"}, 
                            {"lightness": "6"}, 
                            {"gamma": "1"}
                        ]
                    }
                ], 
                {name: 'Leonardo'}
            );
            var customMapTypeId = 'custom_style';

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 7,
                center: {lat: 28, lng: -81.946}, // Florida.
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, customMapTypeId]
                }
            });

            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                map: map
            });

            var start = new google.maps.LatLng(28, -81.946);
            var end = new google.maps.LatLng(41.85, -87.65);

            var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                }
            });

            map.mapTypes.set(customMapTypeId, customMapType);
            map.setMapTypeId(customMapTypeId);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's perfect!